# Lisp - "Trying to bind a non symbol" error

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

i'm a newbie in Lisp and i'm doing a project for college. The project is a simulation of the LMC (Little Man Computer). I have a state that is a list of things (state:ACC acc :PC pc  :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag), "acc" "pc" and "flag" are values, "mem" "in" and "out" are lists.

The one-instruction takes state as parameter and should return a new state, with different values because depending on the result of (nth pc mem) i've to do certain operation. Here for exemple, if the result of (nth pc mem) is between 100 and 199 i call the funcion do-add that should give me a new value for acc for the new state (with some controls that are not implemented yet).

```
(defun one-instruction '(state:ACC acc :PC pc  :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag)
    ((setf (nth pc mem) istruzione)
    (cond ( (0 < istruzione < 99) (do-halt '(state :ACC acc :PC pc :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag))))
          ( (100 < istruzione < 199) (do-add '(state :ACC acc :PC pc :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag)))))))
          ... 

(defun do-add '(state :ACC acc :PC pc  :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag)))
   ((setf (nth pc mem) value)
   ((setf (nth (- value 100) mem) addendo)
   (setf (+ acc addendo) newacc))))
```

When i compile and load the following errors appear:

**++++Error in One-Instruction

Trying to bind a non symbol, (state:ACC acc :PC pc  :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag) and same happens for the "do-add".

So it's wrong the way i pass state as parameter in the two functions? Or maybe i can't use "pc" and "mem" without a getf for example?
Last question, how i can return the whole new state in one-instruction and do-add?
Thanks a lot! (And sorry for bad english, i'm italian :) )

Comment: I'd recommend reading the chapter [5. Functions](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html) of the [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) to see the proper syntax for defining function parameters. You also have some extra parentheses before the `SETF` forms (and the place and value seem to be reversed too), and some infix syntax mixed in for the `COND` tests.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for [`DEFUN`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm) expects an *ordinary lambda-list*, which is in its most basic form an *unevaluated* list of variable names. Your code starts as follows:

```
(defun one-instruction '(state:ACC acc :PC pc  :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag)
   ...)
```

You have two main errors:

- you quoted the list
- your lambda-list is malformed

> Trying to bind a non symbol, (state:ACC acc :PC pc :MEM mem :IN in :OUT out :FLAG flag)

The error is a little bit weird, but remember that `'(a b c)` stands for `(quote (a b c))`, which in the context of a `defun` lambda-list is parsed as a two-element list, `quote` and the `(a b c)` list. The second list is not a symbol, which is how the malformed lambda-list is detected in your case.

The `:pc pc` syntax is used to pass keyword arguments, not to bind them in functions. If you want to define your function properly, with one mandatory state variables and keyword arguments, you should write:

```
(defun one-instruction (state &key acc pc mem in out flag)
  ...)
```

And you would call it as follows:

```
(one-instruction my-state :acc 0 :pc 0 :mem big-table ...)
```

Also, you have:

```
((setf (nth pc mem) istruzione) ...)
```

This is not a valid expression, the expression looks like `(x ...)`, with `x` being the `setf` expression; but `(x ...)` in a normal evaluation context means *function call*, and `(setf ...)` is no function.

---

> In: (setf (nth pc mem) value) i wanted to bind the result of the (nth pc mem), that i'f i'm correct it should give me the value in the list "mem" at the position "pc", to the variable "value"

You do not introduce variables with `setf`, which only modifies existing bindings (and more generally, places). Instead, you have to use [`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm):

```
(let ((instruction (nth n mem)))
  ...)
```

Inside `...`, `instruction` is bound to the value obtained by evaluating `(nth n mem)`.

Note also that your test expressions in `cond` expression are malformed too:

```
(0 < istruzione < 99)
```

The above reads as: *call the function 0 with arguments <, istruzione, < and 99*; there is no function named `0`, and `<` is unbound as a variable. What you wanted instead is:

```
(< 0 istruzione 99)
```

The above is a call to [`<`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/CLHS/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) with multiple arguments, which is true when all the values are sorted according to `<`.

Note also that in the next test, you have `100 < istruzione`, which means both 99 and 100 are corner cases that are not handled by your cond (except if it is on purpose, in which case its fine).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful. So when i DEFINE the funcion i've to write just (state &key x1 x2..) and then ONLY when i call i've to use keyword arguments like (:acc 0 pc:0 ..) ?
For the setf problem, the teacher gave the advice to combine nth and setf. In:
    (setf (nth pc mem) value)
i wanted to bind the result of the (nth pc mem), that i'f i'm correct it should give me the value in the list  "mem" at the position "pc", to the variable "value". So it's not possible to do this in this way? 
Thank you again!

Comment: @Elia Thanks. You'd have to use LET instead, see edit.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it's all clear now! Tonight i'll try to rewrite the project with all this informations! 
So the advice given by teacher to use setf combined with nth it's not for this case? Or maybe i have to use the setf in the "do-add" to change the value of "acc" for the new state after i do the two (let((value(nth ...))) and (let((addendo(nth...))) like (setf acc (+ acc addendo))?